# Mean-value for three functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $f,g,h$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ which are differentiable on $(a,b)$, then prove that there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $$f(a)[g(b)h'(c)-h(b)g'(c)]+h(a)[f(b)g'(c)-g(b)f'(c)]=g(a)[f(b)h'(c)-h(b)f'(c)]$$

This looks very much like (generalized) mean-value theorem, so I'm tempted to write $$i(x)=[h(a)g(b)-g(a)h(b)]f(x)+[f(a)h(b)-h(a)f(b)]g(x)+[g(a)f(b)-f(a)g(b)]h(x)$$

If there exists $c$ such that $i'(c)=0$, we would be done. But here we don't have $i(a)=i(b)$, so I don't know how to reach that conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Define the determinant:
$$
D(x)=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
f(x) & g(x) & h(x) \\
f(a) & g(a) & h(a) \\
f(b) & g(b) & h(b) \\
\end{array}\right|
$$
Note that $D(a)=D(b)=0$, since there will be identical rows. Notice that:
$$
D'(x)=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
f'(x) & g'(x) & h'(x) \\
f(a) & g(a) & h(a) \\
f(b) & g(b) & h(b) \\
\end{array}\right|
$$
and consider using cofactor expansion along the second row.

---

**Note:** Your argument is essentially the same; in fact you do have $i(a)=i(b)$.

Comment: Ohh, at first I saw each term of $i(a)$ has two $a$'s and each term of $i(b)$ has two $b$'s, so they can't be equal. But it seems like $i(a)=i(b)=0$.

Comment: That's a funny mistake to make on my part. Thanks nevertheless!